Futuristic/Dystopian teen book trilogy with people that can breathe underwater
The first book has a light blue background and an arrowhead or shark tooth or something similar in the middle of the cover. If the second book is red, then the third is green and vice versa. The series was released from 2000 - 2020.
Long story short, the human population was separated into different environments (I only remember the sea and mountains) due to this one scientist who I think was trying to save humanity because of global warming or something.
This girl from the sea has to go up to the surface because someone in her ocean community died because some necklace thingy that keeps them alive underwater stopped working out of nowhere. BTW, her father is the leader (I think) of this ocean community and a guy friend goes with her to the surface.
She ends up meeting people with wings embedded in them (like birds) who live in the mountains. She trains with them a bit to fight someone who can somehow help her. Then she goes to this junkyard of a place to meet the person who separated everyone into different environments (his wife died and the girl uses this to convince him to help her in some way). I'm not sure if she got what she wanted, or how this ends, but I know that all this happened in three books.

Above World by Jenn Reese. It's the first book of the Above World trilogy.


Thirteen-year-old Aluna has lived her entire life under the ocean with the Coral Kampii in the City of Shifting Tides. But after centuries spent hidden from the Above World, her colony’s survival is in doubt. The Kampii’s breathing necklaces are failing, but the elders are unwilling to venture above water to seek answers. Only headstrong Aluna and her friend Hoku are stubborn and bold enough to face the terrors of land to search for way to save their people.
But can Aluna’s warrior spirit and Hoku’s tech-savvy keep them safe? Set in a world where overcrowding has led humans to adapt—growing tails to live under the ocean or wings to live on mountains—here is a ride through a future where greed and cruelty have gone unchecked, but the loyalty of friends remains true.

I found it by using Google to search the Goodreads site for necklace breath underwater fantasy site:goodreads.com/book/show/ and it was the top result!
